# populate Data Frame based on lookup data frame in R

Tags: r

How does one go about switching a data frame based on column names between to tables with a lookup table in between.

```
Orig

A B C
1 2 3
2 2 2
4 5 6 

Ret

D E
7 8
8 9
2 4


lookup <- data.frame(Orig=c('A','B','C'),Ret=c('D','D','E'))
  Orig Ret
1  A  D
2  B  D
3  C  E
```

So that the final data frame would be

```
A B C

7 7 8
8 8 9
2 2 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `match` the 'Orig' column in 'lookup' with the column names of 'Orig' to find the numeric index (although, it is in the same order, it could be different in other cases), get the corresponding 'Ret' elements based on that.  We use that to subset the 'Ret' dataset and assign the output back to the original dataset.  Here I made a copy of "Orig".

```
OrigN <- Orig
OrigN[] <- Ret[as.character(lookup$Ret[match(as.character(lookup$Orig), 
           colnames(Orig))])]
OrigN
#  A B C
#1 7 7 8
#2 8 8 9
#3 2 2 4
```

NOTE:  `as.character` was used as the columns in 'lookup' were `factor` class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following will work as well.

```
OrigN <- Orig
OrigN[, as.character(lookup$Orig)] <- Ret[, as.character(lookup$Ret)]
```

This method applies a column shuffle to Orig (actually a copy OrigN following @Akrun) and then fills these columns with the appropriately ordered columns of Ret using the lookup.

Comment: Sure thing, @SQLnRprobs. If this answer was useful, you could give it an "upvote" by clicking on the upper triangle.